# IPSecuritas Mac OS X Snow Leopard CheckPoint VPN

Tags: vpn, mac-osx, checkpoint, osx-snow-leopard

I used to use CheckPoint's VPN client on my Mac OS X (Leopard), but recently I upgraded to Snow Leopard, my VPN client stop working right after that, so I downloaded IPSecuritas and after some time I was able to VPN in. The problem is I get disconnected and since I work through ssh, it's gets very annoying. any ideas where can I look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after very long time playing around i was able to solve this issue

first of all in "Options" i had uncheck MODE_CFG
and the other thing I did was under "General" local side endpoint suppose to be select as a host and that field should be empty, after that it works perfectly for me, no disconnections at all

Answer (score 1):

I don't think snow leopard has been released yet, and is still under NDA/beta.  Not sure how much help you'll get here on this.

Comment: Snow Leopard is due for release in September sometime.

Comment: I've been running preview build for a while and I think it's pretty stable, I haven't had *any* problems at all, and it's more IPSecuritas and CheckPoint question rather then Mac OS X

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Cisco VPN Client (port for OS X)? May work! :D

Download here: https://apps.olin.wustl.edu/computing/help/vpn/vpnclient-darwin-4.9.01.0100-universal-k9.dmg

Comment: i haven't tried with snow leopard but i know for a fact it won't work with checkpoint, i used to use it with cisco on leopard it worked great

Comment: Bummer, have you tried configuring your client as "site" vpn (IPSec)? I think Checkpoint uses some proprietary "user-vpn" crap. 

May be worth looking at VPNC - http://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~massar/vpnc/ , not sure if it would be any help at all, but worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed - configuring IPSecuritas is non-trivial and you need to know specifics about your network settings and configuration. Any advice on a likely route forward?

Answer (score 0):

By changing two binary files of Checkpoints VPN Client it works on Snow Leopard.

http://harald.haentsch.com/?p=1

Answer (score 0):

**FORGET IPSECURITAS IF YOU'RE NOT A VPN ADMINISTRATOR!!!**

Harald Haentsch completely solved this problem by making a very easy to use tutorial on how to "fix" SecureClient to run in OSX 10.6 Snow Leopard:

http://www.sysadmins-world.com/?p=1

I just followed the existing installation steps (I used Hex Fiend instead of 0xED, but any HEX editor should work fine) and it was working in 5 minutes on my Snow Leopard upgrade from OSX 10.5.7.

If you're a techy type and want to know more about the "upgrade existing installation" option ... apparently the only reason SecureClient doesn't work in Snow Leopard is because Checkpoint hard coded "kextload -s" instead of "kextload -d" in the startup files for the SecureClient program.  Snow Leopard doesn't support "-s", but it supports "-d" so all you have to do is copy 2 files from the SecureClient program to a temporary directory, modify the 2 files and copy them back.

Super easy, guaranteed.  It looks like fixing the installation file is also very easy and possibly not necessary in some "new install" situations.

Thanks!!!

-nate